# how to remove category nav from Bueno (Wordpress Theme) header

Tags: themes, navigation

Im helping a friend who has a woo bueno theme [free] blog and for some reason shes chosen long and numerous categories.  these all appear in a nav bar at the very top of her page and it's just got to go. Id appreciate your advice in helping http://veronicapearman.com/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the header, it seems you can either create your own WordPress menu for the `secondary-menu`, or a "woo_custom_navigation" menu. If any of these are set (and maybe they can even be empty), the category list will not be displayed.

You could also create a child theme, with only the `header.php` file. This would be a copy of the `header.php` file of the Bueno theme with the relevant lines removed.

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('has_nav_menu') && has_nav_menu('secondary-menu') ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'catnav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fl', 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu' ) );
} else {
?>
<ul id="catnav" class="nav fl">
    <?php 
    if ( get_option('woo_custom_nav_menu') == 'true' ) {
        if ( function_exists('woo_custom_navigation_output') )
            woo_custom_navigation_output('name=Woo Menu 2');

    } else { ?>
    <?php wp_list_categories('sort_column=menu_order&depth=3&title_li=&exclude='.get_option('woo_nav_exclude')); ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul><!-- /#nav -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this help! It worked. And I'm not even the person who asked the question. :)